# Jest: How to globally mock node-uuid (or any other imported module)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, node-uuid

Recently migrated from `mocha` to `jest` and I'm running into an issue. I have lots of warnings in my tests:

`[SECURITY] node-uuid: crypto not usable, falling back to insecure Math.random()`

Now, adding the following line to each file fixes the issue, but **only** for that specific test file:

`jest.mock('node-uuid', () => ({ v4: jest.fn(() => 1) }));`

I'm hoping there's a way to mock `node-uuid` globally for **all** tests instead of individual files? I've done a bunch of searches and tried different techniques in my setup file, but to no avail.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can define a [manual-mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) in the `[root]/__mocks__/node-uuid.js`
where `[root]` is the directory where the `node_modules` directory is located:

```
module.exports = { v4: jest.fn(() => 1) }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked - 1 important thing to note is that if you have `rootDir` set in config, then the `__mocks__` folder has to go wherever that location is. I would upvote this answer, but I don't have enough rep yet...