# Jest spyOn with uuid breaking in 8.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid, ts-jest

I have a jest spyOn with the uuid which was working in the version 3.4.0 after upgrading it to 8.3.2 the test breaks with the error **Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given**

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
jest.spyOn(uuid, 'v4');
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to mock uuid lib version 8.x is using [Mocking Partials](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials):

```
jest.mock( 'uuid', () => ({
  v4: jest.fn(() => '1234567890' )
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you import uuid

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 ) from uuid;
```

https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#readme

Comment: spyOn cannot be used directly for a method

Comment: My bad, 
I usually use jest.mock instead of jest.spyOn to work with uuid in tests, you can find relevant information on uuid mocks here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383177/how-to-mock-uuid-with-jest